# Web Developing Practices - How do developers hide stream-able content?

Tags: php, web, server, client, content-management-system

Recently, my school project was to design an E-Commerce web store. My store sells various mp3 files for different purposes (instrumentals, stock sounds, etc.). On that store, I use the html `<audio>` tag and some php to stream the content before one were to decide to buy it. However, the issue comes that if this was real store, anyone could just inspect element on the product page and find the source of the audio. They then could proceed to steal it without processing payment. This sparked my curiosity, which led to this question:

*Generally, How do websites that stream media to some degree (Netflix's videos, Spotify's music, etc.) ensure their content can't be easily downloaded by the masses!?*

Comment: They cant, you cant, you send it to my computer, i can capture it

Comment: Well, there is something called the [Encrypted Media Extensions API](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics) that is already [quite widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=eme). It is somewhat contriversial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypted_Media_Extensions

Comment: They can't. It's just not convenient for people to download media on one device while they can have it across multiple devices on those services for only a few bucks a month.